# JavaScript code gives no answer to my isset, how do I solve the problem?

Tags: javascript, php

I have programmed a point system, after successful redeeming I give with `isset($succesMsg)` a message that it was successful.

Now I want to show a small animation using JavaScript, but it does not work.

**My PHP Code**

```
$succesMsg= "<div class='body-overlay' id='body-overlay'></div>
                 <div class='overlay' style='display: none;'><h1><span>+ {$codeCoins['coins']}</span></h1></div>
```

**My HTML Button is:**

```
<input type="submit" name="code" class="btn btn-primary w-100" value="CODE EINLÖSEN">
```

**My JavaScirpt Code is**

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".overlay").hide();
            $(".btn btn-primary w-100").click(function(){
                $(".overlay").show();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.overlay').fadeOut();
                }, 3000);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I click on redeem I see in the source code that the div fields are set (body-overlay and overlay) but the animation does not work.

If I try without the PHP migration it works, but unfortunately brings me nothing.

I can't find the error, I'm searching all the time.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Clicking on the button doesn't trigger anything in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Two mistakes I can see in your code:

1. `$(".btn btn-primary w-100")`

Whenever you want to add an any event using multiple classes of single html element. It should be without space also with dot(`.`).

Explaining: `.btn btn-primary w-100`
It will look for an nested elements with mentioned classes. Like you have html elements are as

```
<div class=‘btn’>
   <div class=‘btn-primary’ >
     <div class=‘w-100’>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Change it to:

```
.btn.btn-primary.w-100
```

2. About `$succesMsg`

you have written a html code in it. Which needs to be loaded first
before javascript code.

Do like: keep your html ready in html only and set varibale true or false in php. And you can check that variable in script. If it is true thane `.show()` or else `.hide()`

Note: Isset checks whether a variable is set and is not NULL only.